# why do I have to swapCursor(null) in onLoaderReset?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, android-loadermanager, android-loader

Android's documentation ( https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html ) says that when I use loaders to do SQL queries, I 
should do swapCursor(null) in onLoaderReset method:

> onLoaderReset
>   This method is called when a previously created loader is being reset, thus making its data unavailable. This callback lets you find out when the data is about to be released so you can remove your reference to it.
>   This implementation calls swapCursor() with a value of null:

```
// This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data.
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
...
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
    // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
    // longer using it.
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

I don't understand why should I swap adapter's cursor to null in onLoaderReset. As far as I know, loader is reset when activity is destroyed. But when activity is destroyed, 
it is eligible for garbage collection and all references that this activity keeps are also eligible for garbage collection. So it doesn't matter if any of those adapters 
keeps e reference to a cursor - it won't prevent the cursor from being garbage collected.

So, why should I swap adapter's cursor to null in onLoaderReset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activities will not be garbage collected if its underlying members are referencing out side of the activity. It will be garbage collected when all its members are may not be used in the future. 
if  `swapCursor(null);` will remove all the underlying references with the cursor. otherwise it will create a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) and your activity will not get garbage collected.

Comment: I think this sentence is not true: "Activities will not be garbage collected if its underlying members are referencing out side of the activity". I think only the opposite is true: Activities will not be garbage collected if they are referenced from outside of the activity

Comment: i don't get any differences from the above two sentences.

Comment: It is the difference between referencing and being referenced.

Comment: ya you are right.. :)  , if the members are being referenced even after activity is destroyed it will create a memory leak.

Comment: Ah, now I (probably) understand. Adapter has registered its listener in cursor and cursor has registered its listener in content resolver - so content resolver refers cursor's listener, cursor's listener refers adapter's listener, adapter's listener refers adapter and adapter refers activity. Is it what you mean?